# How do I get the raw SQL from a DataMapper::Collection?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-datamapper

I'm using the latest versions of postgresql, ruby and datamapper.

I create a query like so:

```
collection = Entry.all(:id => 2..4, :text => /test/)
```

`collection` is a `DataMapper::Collection` object. It's possible to get the `DataMapper::Query` object by simply calling `query = collection.query`. But how do I get the raw SQL of my query, as a String?

I need it because I have to customize the raw SQL (I need `SELECT DISTINCT` instead of only `SELECT`), but I don't want to write the SQL completely by myself, because I'm not sure if I can write a **secure** query.

I would also be happy to archive my goal another way, I'm open to completely new suggestions ;)

Comment: It is better to specify actual version numbers rather than saying "the latest". Think about someone looking at the question two or three years from now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be not so easyly possible, but this is kind of an hackish solution

```
collection = Entry.all(:id => 2..4, :text => /test/)

query = collection.query

DataMapper.repository.adapter.send(:select_statement,query)
```